# CSS: On hover make list item bigger than other children

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/fnu483z0/5/

```
<ul>
<li>link 1</li>
<li>link 2</li>
<li>link 3</li>
<li>link 4</li>
</ul>

ul {
  display: flex;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

The problem is that on hover other items are also affected, they also expand?  Should look like this when hovering an item:

[image]

Comment: In your ul add -> align-items: flex-start; Example -> https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/GQPXEJ

Comment: Can you post this as an answere, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that on hover other items are also affected, they also expand?

Of course they do, because they are all children of the same flex container - and adding padding to one of the items changes the height of the container, so the others grow with it accordingly.

You can easily counter this by giving the hovered item a matching negative margin-bottom:

```
ul li:hover {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: calc(1em - 40px); // your default li padding was 1em,
                                   // so we have to calculate the right difference here
  background-color: #333;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnu483z0/18/

Comment: This works, but I'm confused, what if padding wasn't 1em, but in pixels, what's the calculation, can you give example, please.

Comment: Oh, c’mon, that’s one you can figure out yourself ;-) ... Your LI had a general `padding: 1em`, so now try and find that value again in `calc(1em - 40px)` ...

Answer (score 1):

In your ul add -> 
`align-items: flex-start;`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

ul li:hover {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it breaks if you add `background-color` to `ul`.

Comment: @user3108268 but you have no background color in your example so this is the most correct answer. +1

Comment: It's because list items expand their parent.You should think about your markup and what do you want to achieve.